# Apache: Execute Javascript files like .php files

Tags: php, javascript, apache, node.js

**Apache and PHP**

PHP with Apache is really nice to play with because you can create a random `test.php` with

```
echo '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
```

and when you visit http://myserver.com/test.php it will show `<h1>Hello World</h1>`

**My wish with Apache and JS**

What I would like is to create a file `test.js` with

```
console.log('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
```

and when I visit http://myserver.com/test.js it would show `<h1>Hello World</h1>`

**What's possible currently**

The nearest attempt I found was http://www.modjs.org/ but it is no longer maintained.

Meanwhile we can run a [run a NodeJS instance](http://arguments.callee.info/2010/04/20/running-apache-and-node-js-together/) and simulate apache with file listing and executing javascript files based on the url, but it sucks ...

Anyone knows if it's possible? :)

Thanks!

Comment: nodeJS is usually the way to go.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I'd like a NodeJS instance to be "spawned" when I access the file through Apache. I don't want to have a NodeJS instance running 24/24 for each little script I make.

Comment: Dont work like that, use apache as a proxy in front of node

Answer (score 1):

TeaJS is probably what you are looking for https://code.google.com/p/teajs/ ( https://github.com/ondras/TeaJS )  . You include mod_js in your httpd.conf and then write JavaScript instead of PHP.

```
var hello = request.get('hello');

response.write(hello);
```

Its maturing quickly with database libraries, session handling, and an MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do something like that. Node offers a way nicer eco-system for just demoing. For instance, grab [express](http://www.expressjs.com) and make a nice simple demo:

```
var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/test.php', function(req, res){
    res.send('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Furthermore, `console.log` isn't going to work for emitting code to the user. Use the methods on `res` to write to the user. You can call `res.send` multiple times.

Comment: What are you suggesting? Can't it be done so that javascript on node is run as a CGI? I don't see why not.

Comment: Ah now I see. No you will need some process that runs anytime to respond to requests. This can be a node instance that spawns other node instances, or another webserver like Apache.

Comment: This works on short term, while I'm working on the script. But 1 month later, the process will be dead and the script won't be accessible anymore. And if I'm making 20 tests, I'll have to keep launched 20 nodejs processes.

My Apache is always up and already able to call PHP when I want to view a php file. I'd like to do the same for Javascript. It would make my life a lot easier :P

Comment: You shouldn't start a new process every time. You wouldn't spawn a new Apache process every time you request a PHP file right? Best way I guess is running [forever](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever), listen for file changes and let it restart every time you edit a file.

Comment: Apache has a lot of built-in utilities such as file listing and htaccess. I don't want to rebuild these all with NodeJS. I'm just looking for a way to get Apache treat JS files the same way it does for PHP files.

Comment: @JanJongboom is right, you definitely shouldn't start a new process every time. Also why would you want .js files to be interpreted with Node.js since there are static JavaScript files (for the front-end)? At most you might want .node files. Anyway you should be using Nginx instead of Apache, it's wayyy faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Also not yet mentioned here is working CGI script for Apache -  node-cgi ,  http://larsjung.de/node-cgi/ 
Then you assign file extension via `.htaccess` file to be executed via node.js

I was able to install and make it work with basic scripts, though for files with large dependencies it is still not working for me...

Install procedure is simple (be sure to run it with sudo), I just had to change paths in CGI script (gist of it here https://gist.github.com/quentar/2f5adfa7046082105efa ) in some script but then it works with basic file so that they are executed by node .